# Is it possible to index a simple infinispan cache?

Tags: caching, indexing, infinispan

I want to index my cache to have better response time for my serachs in the cache.

Here how I implemented the infinispan cache :

```
 private Cache createCache(String cacheName) {
    try {
        final Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .indexing()
            .addIndexedEntity(MyEntity.class)
            .simpleCache(true)
            .statistics().enable()

            .build();
        cacheManager.defineConfiguration(cacheName, configuration);
    }catch (RuntimeException ex){

    }
    return cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
}
```

But I got he following exception :

> ISPN000436: Cache 'MyCache' has been requested, but no matching cache configuration exists

Any idea about the reason of error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple caches cannot enable indexing. See: https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#simple-caches_caches